# Unrecognised GOPATH when running Golang program using supervisord

Tags: go, supervisord

I have a Golang program implementing a web server. It is expected to be running continuously, and incase of any unexpected failure or crash, to restart itself. For that, I am trying to configure it as a UNIX-process using `supervisord`. However, the issue I am facing is that the external go libraries included in the code aren't getting recognised as `supervisord` is unable to recognise the `GOPATH`. This is leading to errors such as:

```
web_server.go:11:2: cannot find package "github.com/gorilla/mux" in any of:
    /usr/lib/go/src/github.com/gorilla/mux (from $GOROOT)
    ($GOPATH not set)
```

when running the web server using supervisord. The supervisord configuration for my web server is:

```
[program:web_server]
command=go run web_server.go
directory=/home/ubuntu
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startretries=5
stderr_logfile=/home/ubuntu/err_logs/web_server.err.log
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=1MB
stderr_logfile_backups=10
```

What is the workaround for this?

Answer (score 4):

One important property of `supervisord` as stated [here](http://supervisord.org/subprocess.html#subprocess-environment), that I had been missing out is:

> Subprocesses will inherit the environment of the shell used to start
>   the `supervisord` program. Several environment variables will be set by
>   supervisord itself in the child’s environment also, including
>   `SUPERVISOR_ENABLED` (a flag indicating the process is under supervisor
>   control), `SUPERVISOR_PROCESS_NAME` (the config-file-specified process
>   name for this process) and `SUPERVISOR_GROUP_NAME` (the
>   config-file-specified process group name for the child process).
>
> These environment variables may be overridden within the [supervisord]
>   section config option named `environment` (applies to all subprocesses)
>   or within the per- `[program:x]` section environment config option
>   (applies only to the subprocess specified within the `[program:x]`
>   section).

Therefore, adding the `GOPATH` in the `environment` variable solved the issue.

```
[program:web_server]
command=go run web_server.go
directory=/home/ubuntu
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startretries=5
stderr_logfile=/home/ubuntu/err_logs/web_server.err.log
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=1MB
stderr_logfile_backups=10
environment=GOPATH="/home/ubuntu"
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `go run`. Use `go build` to build a static binary and then run that via supervisord. Your program won't be recompiled (which is what 'go run' does) on each restart and won't require its dependencies to be available each time. Go programs are designed to be compiled into standalone binaries.

Comment: Oh yeah. I missed that. Thanks a lot.

Comment: how to run go build and run the binary?